# Switch no me funciona

Tags: switch

No me funciona el switch, apenas estoy comenzando con JavaScript, y no sé porque al poner el caso 1,me va directamente al default, no entra al case 1, aquí está el código:

[image: switch]

Comment: Bienvenido. Eso no es un problema del lenguaje sino del código. Sube el código para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: intente subir el codigo pero no me deja, por eso adjunté la imagen

Comment: Cómo texto es más cómodo para copiarlo y probarlo. Mejor pasa un enlace a un [pastebin](https://pastebin.com) si no te deja y lo editamos nosotros.

Comment: Hola Limbert Molina, dale al botón edita, quita la imagen y agregá tu código como texto, antes del código pone: **```**, para que aparezca formateado, de esa manera evitarás recibir votos negativos...si no entra al **case 1**, es porque el parámetro que le llega (opcion) no es **1**, verificá que le estas enviando al switch.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda de verdad

Answer (score 1):

El prompt te esta retornando un texto, aunque ingreses un numero, la función retorna una cadena de caracteres, entonces en el switch, case 1, es de tipo numero que falla en evaluar a '1' como texto.

Una de dos, modificas tu switch para evaluar como texto, o conviertes el resultado en numero.

Mira aca:

```js
let option = prompt('Agrega una opcion (1 o 2)');

console.log(typeof option);

switch (option) {
   case 1:
   console.log('Opcion 1');
   break;
   
   case 2:
   console.log('Opcion 2');
   break;
   
   default:
   console.log('Input incorrecto');
   break;
}

switch (option) {

  case '1':
  console.log('Opcion 1 texto');
  break;
  
  case '2':
  console.log('Opcion 2 texto');
  break;
  
  default:
  console.log('Entrada no correcta');
  break;
}
```

Comment: Efectivamente ese era el problema, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que estas recibiendo un valor string y en el "case" tienes puesto el valor 1 como entero. Haz un parseInt a lo que recibes del prompt o en el case por '1', como string. Sld

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [answer] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu respuesta sea marcada como aceptada. También proporciona el código de lo que has hecho (en texto, no imagen) para que comiences  a ganar reputación y medallas.

Comment: Ese era el problema, lo converti a un entero y me funcionó, muchas gracias